# How to join tables using Query DSL

Tags: mysql, jpa, querydsl, predicates

I am using queryDsl for complex search queries in my application. I am new to querydsl. I have started with the below code to fetch few rows from one single table(TableA).
But I have to find list of person(Count) with the same id in some other table(TableB)

```
public static Predicate find(final Long pId)
    QPerson qPerson = QPerson.person;
    Predicate predicate; 
    BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();
    if (pId != null) {
        booleanBuilder.or(qPerson.person_no.eq(pId));
    } 
    if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
        booleanBuilder.or(qPerson.expiry_dt.eq(name));
    }
    predicate = booleanBuilder.getValue();   
    return predicate;
    }
```

TableA:

```
pId         name

1001      sampleNameA
1002      sampleNameB
1003      sampleNameC
```

TableB:

```
pId        name       interests

1001     sampleNameA    music   
1001     sampleNameA    dance
1001     sampleNameA    coding
1003     sampleNameC    music   
1002     sampleNameB    dance
1002     sampleNameB    coding
```

I need to get output like this with below query

select  cnt cnt, tableA.* from master_person_table tableA,(select count(*) cnt from tableB WHERE pId = '1002') cnt
WHERE pId = '1002'

OUTPUT:

```
  count  pId        name       
    2    1002   sampleNameB
```

I need to display the no of rows (for id=1002) in my HTML.

Can anyone please help me in finding the count of the pId to be fetched from tableB

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please paste your output. So that we can help u to build the query.

Comment: @Timo Westkämper  .  I have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: If we look at table2 then count for pId 1002 for dance is 1 & same for coding. And in output you have count as 2. You want count as 1 or 2. can u please gives us more details so that I can help u out. Regards.

Comment: @Pankaj Thanks for your reply. I need to build query with queryDSL. I want the count as 2(actually the count for the id='1002'). My sql query has WHERE condition as id=1002. I need to fetch count based on id column and not based on interest column. I edited the output I want exactly.

Comment: You want ouput for only selected Id or u want it for multiple Ids?

Comment: It could be single id or multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query:-

1.For multiple pIds:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, pId, name FROM TableB GROUP BY pId
```

2.For only selected pId:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, pId, name FROM TableB WHERE pId = 1002
```

If u need more help plz let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need to build query using QueryDSL as I requested. I need to form a queryDSL query for the below one:

select cnt cnt, tableA.* from master_person_table tableA,(select count(*) cnt from tableB WHERE pId = '1002') cnt WHERE pId = '1002'

Comment: It could be done using Q generated classes, Predicates or BooleanBuilder. This way I formed a basic query with one table only and it gave the results. But I need help to join multiple tables. In my query I can pass single id or list of ids from the result of TableA to TableB and I just the count of those ids in TableB. Column name(pID) is same in both tables. Can you help me in building a QueryDSL query.